# How to favorite a Documentation tag?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, tag-watching

Going to the Documentation section and finding your favorite tag is not that easy. One must use the search box to be able to find your favorite tag. Although bookmarking it in my browser will do it, it may not work for everyone in general.

Is there a way to mark as favorite a tag on the Documentation section?

Comment: I could see this working like favorite tags works on the question page, where it shows your favorite tags highlighted and all the rest with lower opacity. Of course, sorting them first would also be nice.

Comment: Where do you feel that this "favorite" should work? In the Q&A site, fav. makes sense since the question list mixes questions, in documentation, once you enter a /tag you are in a tunnel. Topics belonging to other tags wouldn't appear.

Comment: If you switch between the "Documentation (Beta)" and "Tags" links at the right top, you'll see they look eerily similar. Favorite tags in Q&A is useful because it shows questions with new activity based on favorite tags. However favorite tags in Documentation makes sense for a different reason: you work with a (favorite) technology enough so that you'll often want to look for specific examples to help you do your work. Perhaps a favorite tag in documentation could let you browse examples from the Documentation home page (instead of browsing for different tags).