# documentation - "Mark as favorite" button really lacks

Tags: feature-request, documentation, bookmarks

I really need a "star" button for some documentation example. Today I looked through many python pages and examples and found dozens of them that are of use for me.

And since I treat StackOverflow as Knowledge Management platform (my personal attitude to it), I often mark useful pages as favorite. And this feature lacks in Documentation, because I don't want to waste time looking through all the examples again and again.

And no, I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [How to favorite a Documentation tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330086/how-to-favorite-a-documentation-tag) or [Add an ability to star documentation entries as favorite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332764/add-an-ability-to-star-documentation-entries-as-favorite). Both request didn't found that much support, and if there is a reason for not creating this button, I want to be aware of them.

Comment: Since this is apparently not a duplicate (even if it is actually?), I'll just repost my comment from one of the others: *Do people not use bookmarks/favorites any more? I'm genuinely curious. I've got something like 3000 bookmarks in my browser for exactly this purpose.*

Comment: I read this comment already under one of the duplicate questions:) I use bookmarks, but I miss this function in SO Documentation, because it is just more comfortable for me to store the information from SO on the SO site.

Comment: @Mike I didn't know you meant that comment so seriously. For one thing, favorites on SO have the benefit of looking different (in the profile tab) when they've been updated, which you can't really get with bookmarks. Secondly, the 3000-bookmarks approach is hardly ideal. If you're anything like me, you'll not go back to read those any time soon if ever. I ended up dumping my bookmarks into large spreadsheets a while back, with labels for priority, etc. I agree, though, that there's really no reason to post this exact dupe. "didn't find that much support" doesn't really count.

Comment: @Frank I just wanted to note that this request didn't request anything that bookmarks in a browser can't already do. The additional features of favorites on SO Q&A (like change tracking) make the feature more compelling.